# how to use market basket analysis (apriori) sql server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas, business-intelligence

I want to finish my final project, my project is about market basket analysis with apriori algorthm.
I use C# and SQL server 2005.
Can  you help me please.
I have a saving mart datasets.
I am newbie and I don't know step-step how to use market basket analysis on sql server 2005.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems too general a question, as there are a lot of subtleties to market basket analysis depending upon the situation. Where are you having a problem?

If you have not already done so, try starting here:

[Market Basket Analysis in SSAS 2005+](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Market-Basket-Analysis.aspx)